# How to build and deploy python project with test suite

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-unittest

I have a simple command-line python project with the following structure

```
project_main/
    - README.md
    - requirements.txt
    - setup.py
    - project_main/
          - __init__.py
          - controller.py
    - tests/
          - __init__.py
          - test_cases.py
          - test_suite.py
```

I run the test cases using the command given below, and all tests pass OK

```
python -m unittest
```

The application logic works perfectly.

Now I need to deploy this code in any system with a single script "setup.py". The contents of "setup.py" is given below

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))) 
setup(
    name='sample',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='sample deployment'
    packages=find_packages(),
    test_suite="tests.test_suite.main_suite",
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'demoCommand=project_main.controller:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

When I run this using the below command, it asks for admin permissions to the default install path. Also even if test_cases fail, the application gets installed.

```
python3 setup.py install
```

1. I would like to know how to ensure all the packages in requirements.txt are installed when running the setup.py file?
2. How to stop installation if test cases fail?
3. How to install the application in a custom folder without admin permission?

EDIT: Adding partial relevant output of the setup.py install command

```
copying build\lib\tests\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\tests
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\tests\main_test_suite.py to main_test_suite.cpython-37.pyc
```

Comment: Usually tests are ran before the code is deployed, not while it's being installed

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't mind that too. But i want it in the deployment flow instead of manually doing it everytime

Comment: @cricket_007 the fact that setup.py has an option to mention the "test_suite" option means that, running tests should be factored in the setuptools flow. But i think i am missing some other settings to enforce this

Comment: The `test_suite` argument is only used by the `python setup.py test` invocation. It is not used by the `install` subcommand or any other. If you want, you can include the tests in the package so the user can then run them if necessary - like `numpy` or `pandas` do it. Running tests _while_ installing the package, especially aborting the installation on failing tests is a bad idea. You should ensure your package is installable before releasing it.